# "Table already exists" when changing PK autoincrement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am quite new to MySQL and I have encountered a problem that I find quite puzzling. If I create a table with MySQL Workbench, when I set the PK I can choose it to auto-increment or not, as should be. However, if I change my mind later on, once the table has been created, I cannot alter the auto-increment flag any longer, as MySQL tells me that the "table already exists". That happens even if the table is empty.

The auto-generated SQL is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

and it fails with the error stated above. I have tried changing the algorithm and lock type, to no avail.

This does not happens in T-SQL or Oracle, for instance, so I fail to see a reason why it should fail in MySQL. Is there any way to fix this without having to drop and re-create the table?

Thanks.

Comment: this shouldn't be happpening, are you really naming your table `table`? check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6309/1 everything works fine.

Comment: you should try to change the `table name` don't use the table because table is one the function....

Comment: @legrojan, did you got it or not..

Comment: Yes, sorry, my table is not named "table", I just used that to avoid what would be a meaningless name to anyone but me, and I failed to see that "table" is a reserved word. Will change the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I discovered the culprit thanks to dbForge Studio. The same thing happens there, but this time the error is more explicit: I cannot change the auto-increment flag apparently because it is used as a foreign key on another table. I deleted the FK and then I was able to set the auto-increment.

Thank you all who helped me, I have learned some new things thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

From experience all the GUIs get a bit confused when you start changing primary keys, the number of error messages I've seen from SQL Server...

You don't need to drop the whole table, but it might be easiest to drop and then re-create the offending column.

Also, check out the MySQL dev docs, but I think either ALTER or MODIFY column are the two I'd go for and I'm not sure why the column name is there twice if you're not renaming it.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried to remove one of the name columns and it is not a valid syntax, it appears it must indeed be repeated.